# runtime error в яндекс контесте для аналитиков

Tags: python

Есть задача, написала для нее код, в pyCharm все нормально компилируется, у них на сайте выдает runtime error.

Сотрудники Яндекса любят играть в мини-футбол по выходным. В каждом матче играют две команды по 5 человек. Состав на игру в каждую команду выбирается случайно равновероятно из всех сотрудников Яндекса.

Аркадий ведет статистику всех игр. Он записывает состав каждой команды и финальный счет игры. Кроме этого, он ведет статистику каждого игрока по разнице мячей: каждому игроку матча добавляется разница мячей команды, в составе которой он играл. Разница мячей считается как число голов cвоей команды минус число голов противоположной команды. Изначально статистика по разнице мячей для каждого игрока равна 0.

Помогите Аркадию понять его прогресс в сезоне. После каждого матча нужно посчитать количество игроков с разницей мячей больше, чем у Аркадия.

Формат ввода

В первой строке записано два числа: N (10 ≤ N ≤ 10000) - число сотрудников, M (1 ≤ M ≤ 100000) — число футбольных матчей. Затем следуют результаты каждого матча.

В первой строке каждого матча записано два числа, gA, gB (0 ≤ gA, gB ≤ 20) — количество голов, которые забили команды A и B.

Во второй строке каждого матча записаны десять чисел pi (0 ≤ pi < N) — id сотрудников, участвовавших в матче. Первые пять - состав команды A, вторые пять - состав команды B.

Гарантируется, что составы команд для каждого матча выбирались случайно равновероятно.

У Аркадия id всегда равно 0.

Формат вывода

Для каждого футбольного матча выведите одно целое число — количество игроков с разницей

мячей больше, чем у Аркадия.
Мой код:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

emp_matches = np.array(sys.stdin.readline().split(), dtype=np.int16)
gamers_stats = pd.Series(np.zeros(emp_matches[0]), dtype=np.int16)

for i in range(emp_matches[1]):
    score = np.array(sys.stdin.readline().split(), dtype=np.int16)
    teams = np.array(sys.stdin.readline().split(), dtype=np.int16)
    dif = score[0] - score[1]

    gamers_stats[teams[:5]] += dif
    gamers_stats[teams[5:]] -= dif

print(len(gamers_stats[gamers_stats > gamers_stats[0]]))
```

Тестовые данные:

```
10 1
6 15
8 1 0 3 9 2 6 5 4 7
```

Вывод:

```
5
```

Что написано в выводе чекера яндекса:

```
Completion status: ABNORMAL_EXIT
Term sig: null
Error code: 1
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять, в чем я ошиблась(